# Trying to make automated traffic lights

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

Hi Im trying to make a set of automated traffic lights but I can't get them to stop running. I have tried using window.clearInterval() but it won't work. Im doing this for my controlled assessment for my GCSE. I really don't know why this won't work so any help would be great. Thanks.

```js
var asset = [
    "redyellow.png",
    "green.png",
    "yellow.png",
    "red.png"
];

var counter = 0;

function changeLights() {

    if (counter == asset.length) counter = 0;

    var image = document.getElementById('redImg');
    image.src=asset[counter];

    counter = counter + 1;
}

var toggle = 1

function timer() {
  if (toggle === 1) {
    var on = setInterval(changeLights,5000)
  }
  else {
    window.clearInterval()
  }
}

function stopTimer() {
  toggle = toggle + 1
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Traffic Lights</h1>

<img id="redImg" src="red.png" alt="Red traffic light" />
<p>
  <button type="button" onclick="timer()">Start Lights</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="stopTimer()">Stop Lights</button>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making the interval a global variable. Also you need to call `self.clearInterval(interval)`. For example:

```
var interval;

function timer() {
    interval = self.setInterval(changeLights, 5000);
}

function stopTimer() {
    self.clearInterval(interval);
}
```

In your case:

```js
var asset = [
  "redyellow.png",
  "green.png",
  "yellow.png",
  "red.png"
];
var counter = 0;
var interval = null;

function changeLights() {
  if (counter == asset.length) counter = 0;
  var image = document.getElementById('redImg');
  image.src = asset[counter];
  image.alt = asset[counter]; // debug
  counter = counter + 1;
}


function timer() {
  if (!interval) {
    interval = self.setInterval(changeLights, 1000);
  }
}

function stopTimer() {
  self.clearInterval(interval);
  interval = null;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h1>Traffic Lights</h1>

  <img id="redImg" src="red.png" alt="Red traffic light" />
  <p>
    <button type="button" onclick="timer()">Start Lights</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="stopTimer()">Stop Lights</button>
  </p>

</body>

</html>
```

Note that I changed it in some ways, most notably removing the code having to do with `toggle`. This version also allows you to start it again without reloading the page, and prevents you from starting multiple intervals, which would require reloading the page to stop.